# Deploying tessract ocr on AIX6

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, aix

How to deploy Tessaract OCR on AIX6 with GCC version 4.0.0.

We got following errors while deploying :

libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -MT jpegio.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/jpegio.Tpo -c jpegio.c  -DPIC -o .libs/jpegio.o

jpegio.c:112:21: error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory

jpegio.c:114: error: expected ')' before 'cinfo'

jpegio.c:115: error: expected ')' before 'cinfo'

jpegio.c:122: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'jpeg_comment_callback'

jpegio.c: In function 'pixReadStreamJpeg':

jpegio.c:228: error: 'JSAMPROW' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:228: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

jpegio.c:228: error: for each function it appears in.)

jpegio.c:228: error: expected ';' before 'rowbuffer'

jpegio.c:231: error: storage size of 'cinfo' isn't known

jpegio.c:232: error: storage size of 'jerr' isn't known

jpegio.c:246: error: 'BITS_IN_JSAMPLE' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:254: error: 'rowbuffer' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:260: error: 'jpeg_error_do_not_exit' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:265: error: 'JPEG_COM' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:265: error: 'jpeg_comment_callback' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:271: error: 'JCS_GRAYSCALE' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:278: error: 'JCS_YCCK' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:279: error: 'JCS_CMYK' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:286: error: expected ';' before 'calloc'

jpegio.c:290: error: expected ';' before 'calloc'

jpegio.c:336: error: 'JDIMENSION' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:336: error: expected ')' before numeric constant

jpegio.c:374: error: expected ')' before numeric constant

jpegio.c: In function 'freadHeaderJpeg':

jpegio.c:472: error: storage size of 'cinfo' isn't known

jpegio.c:473: error: storage size of 'jerr' isn't known

jpegio.c:492: error: 'jpeg_error_do_not_exit' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:503: error: 'JCS_YCCK' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:505: error: 'JCS_CMYK' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c: In function 'fgetJpegResolution':

jpegio.c:530: error: storage size of 'cinfo' isn't known

jpegio.c:531: error: storage size of 'jerr' isn't known

jpegio.c:546: error: 'jpeg_error_do_not_exit' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c: In function 'pixWriteStreamJpeg':

jpegio.c:655: error: 'JSAMPROW' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:655: error: expected ';' before 'rowbuffer'

jpegio.c:657: error: storage size of 'cinfo' isn't known

jpegio.c:658: error: storage size of 'jerr' isn't known

jpegio.c:670: error: 'rowbuffer' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:700: error: 'jpeg_error_do_not_exit' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:710: error: 'JCS_GRAYSCALE' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:714: error: 'JCS_RGB' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:757: error: 'JPEG_COM' undeclared (first use in this function)

jpegio.c:757: error: expected ')' before 'JOCTET'

jpegio.c:763: error: expected ')' before 'calloc'

jpegio.c:784: error: expected expression before ')' token

jpegio.c: At top level:

jpegio.c:1115: error: expected ')' before 'cinfo'

jpegio.c:1125: error: expected ')' before 'cinfo'

jpegio.c:1144: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'jpeg_comment_callback'

make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.

make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.

make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2.

Comment: When you encounter an unresoved dependency, you should just install the missing components. In this case it is libjpeg: http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v9b.tar.gz

Comment: Thank you Zsigmond I will try it .